# OPEN TK C# Loading Minecraft json and drawing object

Tags: json, opengl, minecraft, opentk

I'm creating a simple code to read minecraft json and generate on the screen, cube textures work without problems, but textures like the torch are bad, the idea is to be able to read any minecraft json and reproduce it on the screen, I tried to map, but I could not.
Every image becomes a face of the cube I wish I could shape it to be the size of the read texture.

```
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OpenGLTestes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
               
        int downX, downY;
        float xangle, yangle, fov;
        int texTop;
        int texBottom;
        int texSideFront;
        int texSideBack;
        int texSideLeft;
        int texSideRight;

        string AppPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Images\\";

        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat ForBitmapData = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
        OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat ForTextImage2D = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgr;

        private int UploadTexture(string pathname)
        {
            // Create a new OpenGL texture object
            int id = GL.GenTexture();

            // Select the new texture
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, id);

            //Verificando o tipo de Imagem
            if (pathname.Substring(pathname.Length - 3, 3).ToUpper() == "PNG")
            {
                ForBitmapData = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
                ForTextImage2D = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra;
            }
            else
            {
                ForBitmapData = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
                ForTextImage2D = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgr;
            }

            // Load the image
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pathname);

            // Lock image data to allow direct access
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmp_data = bmp.LockBits(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                    ForBitmapData);

            // Import the image data into the OpenGL texture
            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D,
                          0,
                          PixelInternalFormat.Rgba,
                          bmp_data.Width,
                          bmp_data.Height,
                          0,
                          ForTextImage2D,
                          OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelType.UnsignedByte,
                          bmp_data.Scan0);

            // Unlock the image data
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmp_data);

            // Configure minification and magnification filters
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);

            //GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS , (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);
            //GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);

            // Return the OpenGL object ID for use
            return id;
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
      

        private void glControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GL.ClearColor(Color.Blue);
            //xangle = 45;
            //yangle = 25;

            //Lighting
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Lighting);
            //GL.Enable(EnableCap.ColorMaterial); //para o Light não afetar a cor do material

            //Definindo a Light0
            float[] Light_Position = {10,10,20};
            GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Position, Light_Position);

            float[] Light_Difuse = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }; //color light
            GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Diffuse, Light_Difuse);

            float[] Light_Ambient = { 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f };//color light Ambiente
            GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Ambient, Light_Ambient);

            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Light0);

            //Texturing
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
            GL.GenerateMipmap(GenerateMipmapTarget.Texture2D); //Mapea a mesma imagem de varios tamanhos

            texTop = UploadTexture(AppPath + "torch.png");
            texBottom = UploadTexture(AppPath + "torch.png");
            texSideBack = UploadTexture(AppPath + "torch.png");
            texSideFront = UploadTexture(AppPath + "torch.png");
            texSideLeft = UploadTexture(AppPath + "torch.png");
            texSideRight = UploadTexture(AppPath + "torch.png");

            //GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
            GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactor.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactor.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
            
        }

        private void glControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            Matrix4 perspetiva = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(1.0f, 4 / 3, 1, 10000); //Setup Perspective
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
            GL.LoadIdentity();                 // load the identity matrix
            GL.LoadMatrix(ref perspetiva);

            Matrix4 camera = Matrix4.LookAt(200, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0); //Setup camera
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview); //Load Camera
            GL.LoadIdentity();
            GL.LoadMatrix(ref camera);

            GL.Viewport(0, 0, glControl.Width, glControl.Height);  //Size of window
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest); //Enable correct Z Drawings
            GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Less) ;  //Enable correct Z Drawings

            GL.Rotate((yangle * -1), 0, 0, 1);
            GL.Rotate(xangle, 0, 1, 0);
            
            int Tam = 45;

            //Front
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texSideFront);
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
            GL.Color3(Color.White);
            GL.Normal3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(Tam, -Tam, Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(Tam, -Tam, -Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(Tam, Tam, -Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(Tam, Tam, Tam);
            GL.End();

            //Back
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texSideBack);
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
            GL.Color4(Color.Cyan);
            GL.Normal3(-1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam, -Tam, Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam, -Tam, -Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam, Tam, -Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam, Tam, Tam);
            GL.End();

            //Right
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texSideRight);
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
            GL.Color3(Color.Yellow);
            GL.Normal3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam, -Tam, -Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(Tam, -Tam, -Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(Tam, Tam, -Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(1,0);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam, Tam, -Tam);
            GL.End();


            //Top
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texTop);
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
            GL.Color3(Color.Green);
            GL.Normal3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
            GL.Vertex3( Tam, Tam, Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
            GL.Vertex3( Tam, Tam,-Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam, Tam,-Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam, Tam, Tam);
            GL.End();

            //Botton
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texBottom);
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
            GL.Color3(Color.Blue);
            GL.Normal3(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
            GL.Vertex3( Tam,-Tam, Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
            GL.Vertex3( Tam,-Tam,-Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam,-Tam,-Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam,-Tam, Tam);
            GL.End();

            //Right
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texSideRight);
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
            GL.Color3(Color.White);
            GL.Normal3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam, -Tam, Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(Tam, -Tam, Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(0,0);
            GL.Vertex3(Tam, Tam, Tam);
            GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(-Tam, Tam, Tam);
            GL.End();
            

            glControl.VSync = true; 
            glControl.SwapBuffers(); 

        }

        private void glControl_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            downX = e.X;
            downY = e.Y;
        }

        private void glControl_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.X == downX && e.Y == downY) return;

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                xangle += (e.X - downX) * 0.05f;
                yangle += (e.Y - downY) * 0.05f;
                glControl.Invalidate();
                glControl.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}

Example:
template_torch.json
{
   "ambientocclusion": false,
   "textures": {
       "particle": "#torch"
   },
   "elements": [
       {   "from": [ 7, 0, 7 ],
           "to": [ 9, 10, 9 ],
           "shade": false,
           "faces": {
               "down": { "uv": [ 7, 13, 9, 15 ], "texture": "#torch" },
               "up":   { "uv": [ 7,  6, 9,  8 ], "texture": "#torch" }
           }
       },
       {   "from": [ 7, 0, 0 ],
           "to": [ 9, 16, 16 ],
           "shade": false,
           "faces": {
               "west": { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16 ], "texture": "#torch" },
               "east": { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16 ], "texture": "#torch" }
           }
       },
       {   "from": [ 0, 0, 7 ],
           "to": [ 16, 16, 9 ],
           "shade": false,
           "faces": {
               "north": { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16 ], "texture": "#torch" },
               "south": { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16 ], "texture": "#torch" }
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the JSON file and see what is different between the torch and the block? Minecraft JSONs are *complicated*. The texture does not say how big the torch is - the JSON says that.

Comment: in fact the json looks like it has the coordinates, the apeba texture covers the object, but that's the problem because the texture changes in size too

Comment: I inserted an example from json

Comment: the texture does not change in size

Comment: So it’s not that the texture changes in size, see the code I put, if I decrease the cube the texture will be shown smaller, that’s why I don’t want it to happen, that is, if I have a png file that is 20 x 20 and put in a 40 by 40 cube it will cover the entire cube I would not like that to happen, but this is only part of the problem, in json I would like to identify the dimensions of the object that must be modified before applying the texture

Comment: That's why the model file has UV texture coordinates in it.

Comment: Exactly this is my doubt how to get this uv mapping inside the texture by opentk, that is, with the data from json it is possible to shape the object and map the texture on the faces of the object, but I was unable to do this kkk.

Comment: GL.TexCoord(0, 0) <- those are texture coordinates